# JSF & jqPlot Uncaught TypeError

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, charts, jqplot

I have a problem using jqPlot with JSF

I added this code to my JSF page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var s1 = [200, 600, 700, 1000];
  var s2 = [460, - 210, 690, 820];
  var s3 = [-260, - 440, 320, 200];
  var ticks = ['May', 'June', 'July', 'August'];
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1, s2, s3], {
    // The "seriesDefaults" option is an options object that will
    // be applied to all series in the chart.
    seriesDefaults: {
      renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
      rendererOptions: {
        fillToZero: true
      }
    },
    series: [{
      label: 'Hotel'
    }, {
      label: 'Event Regristration'
    }, {
      label: 'Airfare'
    }],
    legend: {
      show: true,
      placement: 'outsideGrid'
    },
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
        ticks: ticks
      },
      yaxis: {
        pad: 1.05,
        tickOptions: {
          formatString: '$%d'
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

but when I try to load the page I got this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'BarRenderer' of undefined
(anonymous function)portfolioModeling.xhtml:184
f.extend._Deferred.e.resolveWithjquery.min.js:2
e.extend.readyjquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.C
```

I added the whole required js files and also the css file but I am lost and don't know where is the problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: I solved the problem

The issue was the I included the style sheets and js files in the head and the causes a big problem to the jsf mvc projects

so I moved them to the body and it worked just fine

thanks

Answer (score 4):

That can happen if you're using a JSF component library which by itself **already** ships with jQuery, such as PrimeFaces, RichFaces, ICEfaces, etc.

You should then not include another version of jQuery, that would only lead to JavaScript errors in all colors.

If you have a jQuery plugin and a script which depends on it, then you should rather be adding it as `<h:outputScript target="head">` inside the `<h:body>` instead of inside the `<h:head>`. This way you can guarantee that it's loaded *after* the JSF component library bundled jQuery.

```html
<h:head>
    ...
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery.jqplot.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/onload.js" target="head" />
    ...
</h:body>
```

The JSF component library bundled jQuery may however *only* be auto-included when the view contains components which explicitly requires jQuery. If the view doesn't contain it, then jQuery may not be auto-included and your plugin and script would then break. If you need to force inclusion of jQuery on *every* view, then you'd need to explicitly declare it in `<h:outputScript>` in the `<h:head>`.

It's unclear which component library you're using but in case of PrimeFaces it's

```html
<h:head>
    ...
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery.jqplot.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/onload.js" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    ...
</h:body>
```

*(which would however be strange to manually fiddle with jqPlot, as PrimeFaces already offers several JSF components which use jqPlot under the covers)*

and in case of RichFaces 4.x it's

```html
<h:head>
    ...
    <h:outputScript name="jquery.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery.jqplot.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/onload.js" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    ...
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem

The issue was the I included the style sheets and js files in the head and the causes a big problem to the jsf mvc projects

Answer (score 0):

Just posting back here as I solved the same error by including some fundamental script references that weren't included in the tutorial I was following.

The missing lines from the header section in the HTML were (note that the library location './lib...' will vary depending on the local installation path):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./lib/dist/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./lib/dist/jquery.jqplot.css">
```

Hope this helps someone,

James

Answer (score -1):

the problem from JQuery file, u need to call jquery.js